# VK API ошибка в доступе

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Привет.
Я создал свое приложение как полагается. И все у меня работает Но только для моего токена.
Суть вот в чем: через CURL я посылаю запрос для метода messages.get и он работает отлично. Но стоит использовать другой токен в приложении как на выходе получается следующая картина:

```
 {"error":{"error_code":17,"error_msg":"Validation required: please open redirect_uri in browser 1056693590","request_params":[{"key":"oauth","value":"1"},{"key":"method","value":"messages.get"},{"key":"user_id","value":"156961900"},{"key":"v","value":"5.37"},{"key":"out","value":"0"},{"key":"count","value":"10"}],"redirect_uri":"https:\/\/m.vk.com\/login?act=security_check&api_hash=ХЭШ"}}
```

Таким образом, я в ступоре. Ибо на localhost все работает даже с дуругим токеном (по крайней мере вчера работало ха-ха), но на хосте для юзеров кроме меня - нет.

На всякий случай:

1. Все пользователи добавили себе мое приложение.
2. Через адресную
       строку, используя любой зарегестрированный токен, я могу получить
       результат.
3. В настройках приложения указаны рабочие base domain, auth
       url, site address

Comment: Токен должен быть получен на том же самом устройстве, на котором вы его будете использовать, то есть на хосте. Ну или откройте этот самый `redirect_uri` прямо с хоста

Comment: Получается рекурсия в таком случае.
Получаю redirect_uri, перехожу, получаю снова ту же ошибку. После чего все повторяется.

Comment: Для приложений, работающих с сервера (не через запросы с клиентского компа) предусмотрен другой способ генерации токена. Полученный токен не будет зависеть от ip, но там есть какие-то ограничения. Ссылку на документацию прямо сейчас скинуть не могу, только чуть позже

Comment: Что-то типо OAuth, как я понял. Вероно?

Comment: Переходите-то точно на хосте, а не с домашнего браузера?

Comment: Да. CURL  иначе не сможет

Answer (score 1):

Согласно [документации](https://vk.com/dev/access_token), есть 3 способа получения получения ключа доступа (access token):

1. [Implicit flow](https://vk.com/dev/implicit_flow_user) - самый простой (одношаговый) способ, но ключ будет работать только с запросами, отправленными с устройства, с которого была произведена авторизация. Подойдет для десктопных, мобильных или javascipt приложений.
2. [Authorization code flow](https://vk.com/dev/authcode_flow_user) - двухшаговый способ, более сложный, но полученный access token не будет привязан к ip клиента, запросы можно отправлять с сервера. Есть некоторые ограничения на разрешаемые права, например нельзя получить доступ к messages.
3. [Client credentials flow](https://vk.com/dev/client_cred_flow) - авторизация по секретному ключу приложения. Необходимо только для доступа доступа к специальным secure-методам.

В вашем случае нужно использовать 2 метод:

- Сначала с клиентского устройства идет запрос вида

  ```
  https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=1&  // id приложения
      display=page&  // тип страницы авторизации
      redirect_uri=http://example.com/callback&  // куда производится переход после авторизации
      scope=friends&  // к чему хотим получить доступ
      response_type=code&  // тип ответа, который нам нужен
      v=5.63
  ```

  После редиректа получаем код, который используем во втором запросе:

  ```
  http://REDIRECT_URI#code=XXXXXXXX
  ```
- С сервера отправляем запрос вида:

  ```
  https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id=1&  // id приложения
      client_secret=H2Pk8htyFD8024mZaPHm&  // Защищенный ключ приложения - смотрим в настройках приложения, там же где и id
      redirect_uri=http://mysite.ru&  // Куда переходим после запроса
      code=XXXXXXXX  // Код, полученный на предыдущем шаге
  ```

  В результате уже получаем access token, который уже используем в запросах со стороны сервера:

  ```
  {"access_token":"YYYYYYYYYYY", "expires_in":43200, "user_id":ZZZZZ}
  ```

Comment: Второй не подойдет. Мне нужны messages.

Comment: @SergeyKarsten, тогда вам как-то нужно отправлять запросы с клиентского устройства. По-другому, судя по документации, не получится.

Comment: Вот я тоже голову ломаю..